# what is the best application to store log in my spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am developing a new project to learn how work microservices in a spring boot app, but i don't know what is the best wey to store and search log becose i think that storing logs in files is a bad solution.
I have read about kibana, but i wont to know what is the most common or the best application to store my logs.
thanks and sorry for my english is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many 3rd party tools, which offer log collection services, which come with an easy integration for a SpringBoot app.

Some of these are ...

- Splunk
- DataDog
- NewRelic

I personally have a good experience with [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/). It allows you to collect logs and do a lot of useful stuff with them. Think analytics, or dashboard creation. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426758/splunk-integration-with-spring-boot) how to integrate Splunk with your SpringBoot app.

Sure, you can go for Kibana and the ELK stack, but you'd need to either configure and run it yourself or get it from a 3rd party provider like AWS.
This, according to my expectations, would take you 2-3 times the time as with using Splunk, for example.

Comment: Hi, Arthur Thank you so much for your answer, i will try Splunk